# MsProject: Set Baseline for a big number of tasks

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I'm working on a a small addin which allows me to edit set my baseline depending of a SQL request.

This is my current code:

```
foreach (ReturnEnumTasks i_objsectionTask in l_objTaskList)
{
    MSProject.Task l_objTaskSection = taskManagement.getTask(l_objProject, new Guid(i_objsectionTask.taskUID));

    if (l_objTaskSection != null)
    {
        foreach (MSProject.Task i_objTask in g_objProject.Tasks)
        {
            if (!i_objTask.Summary)
            {
                if (i_objTask.OutlineNumber.like(l_objTaskSection.OutlineNumber + "%"))
                {
                    baselineManagement.setBaseline(l_objProject, i_objTask, m_objBaselineNumber);
                    baselineManagement.setBaseline(l_objProject, i_objTask, baselineNumber.baseline0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the idea, I have a SQL query which returns me the the tasks with a special wbs

After that, I convert these strings into Tasks object with a function I built.
Once, it's done I set my baseline for the task.

The problem is the following if, I have 100 tasks, my addin took more than 30 seconds to do the calculation.

So I'd like to know if there is a way to select all of my tasks and store them in Tasks object and after that make one setbaseline for the whole selection

Because I made some trials and apparently it's better to select all the tasks and set the baseline than to set the baseline one by one

Comment: Are you using Aspose instead of the native object model? If so, consider adding that tag. FWIW: using the [BaselineSave method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.baselinesave) of the Project Application object, you can set the baseline for selected tasks, but that requires having the file open in MS Project.

Comment: I never hear about Aspose until today
So I understand well, it's a object which allows to read and write in MSproject, right?

Comment: What is the `setBaseline` method you are using, then? It would seem you have two choices: if `setBaseline` is something you created, try to speed it up; otherwise use the native MS Project object model _within_ MS Project where you can set baseline for multiple tasks at a time, but you need to have the file opened within MS Project.